# Find date range if overlap with other dates in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, overlap

**Firstly, I don't know if it is called date overlapping or what,**

I am going to present my query here:

I have a sample data in the mongoDB database which is is as following:

```
{
  "merchantId": {
    "$oid": "62c950dfc96c2b690028be88"
  },
  "contactInfo": {
    "name": "Claudia Shields",
    "phoneNumber": 8904672101
  },
  "location": {
    "address": "737 applegate court",
    "city": "bowie",
    "state": "rhode island",
    "country": "greece",
    "zipCode": 10825
  },
  "price": 16,
  "parkingType": "residence",
  "parkingInfo": [
    {
      "parkingName": "Fountain Avenue",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d12053cb03235286511d55"
      },
      "default": []
    }
  ],
  "totalSpots": [
    127
  ],
  "coordinates": {
    "lng": 34.048954,
    "lat": 10.299556
  },
  "status": "active",
  "isFeePaid": false,
  "parkingZone": [],
  "availability": [
    {
      "day": "Saturday",
      "startTime": "09:00",
      "endTime": "14:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13355bd1ad85d85ae4b4b"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Monday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13375bd1ad85d85ae4b4f"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Tuesday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d1337cbd1ad85d85ae4b53"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Wednesday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13383bd1ad85d85ae4b57"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Thursday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13390bd1ad85d85ae4b5b"
      }
    },
    {
      "day": "Friday",
      "startTime": "08:00",
      "endTime": "16:00",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d13396bd1ad85d85ae4b5f"
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

If I send following request then I am getting a result of that particular day. No problem whatsoever. Eg: I am sending the request for date `25-july,2022` and that day is Monday and duration is also of the same date (endTime: "`2022-07-25 14:00`"), So it Is working completely fine.

```
{
    "city":"bowie",
    "startTime": "2022-07-25 11:00",
    "duration":{
        "days":"0",
        "hours":"3",
        "minutes":"00"
    }
}
```

below is the route to get data:

```
exports.getParkingListByCriteria = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    endTime = getEndTime(req.body.startTime, req.body.duration);
    const startTime = dayjs(req.body.startTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").format(
      "dddd"
    );
    let parkings = await Parking.find(
      {
        "location.city": req.body.city,
      },
      {
        availability: { $elemMatch: { day: startTime } },
        totalSpots: 1,
        ...
      }
    );
    parkingList = [];
    parkings.filter((parking) => {
      if (isParkingAvailable(parking.availability, req.body.startTime, endTime))
        parkingList.push(parking);
    });

    res.status(200).send(parkingList);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Now the problem arises and that is ->  When duration exceeds more than 24 hours then it is returning an empty array and not showing data of that day

Eg: If the duration exceeds more than 24 hours then my code should automatically go to Day Tuesday and show me the data of Monday and Tuesday because the startTime is `2022-07-25 11:00` and endTime would be `2022-07-26 11:00`. But it is not doing that and returning an empty array

Comment: What's the reason for not storing the `endTime` in the document?

Comment: For which collection are you talking about. It is stored in a Parking list and booking list.